# Ensure concurrency within ConcurrentSkipListMap

Tags: java, dictionary

I have a problem with understanding concureency for ConcurrentSkipListMap.

I have the following declaration:

```
ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, Configuration>> map
```

Could just as well be used in such a form as below?

```
ConcurrentSkipListMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Configuration>> map
```

Can be preserved concurrency at all the map data?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: More information on how the map will be used would be useful - as answers indicate, the required 'concurrency' depends on usage.

Comment: A map of maps? Sounds fishy; what are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @fge I have data in a form: 
The main map has a key as its identifier for a category, within the category I have a map, which contains all articles (key as string of characters, value as entity article). These data must be concurrent because they are available for many clients in RESTful WebService.

Answer (score 2):

It really depends on how the *inner map* is accessed.

If you do not have any concurrency on this inner map, then you can declare it as `HashMap`. Otherwise, if multiple threads may access it concurrently, then you should use a concurrent structure such as `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on operations, that you want to have. For example, if you need to have putIfAbsent at nested map, than you need to have nested ConcurrentSkipListMap. 
If you will get a nested map and work with it from multithreaded code it should be Concurrent<...>Map also.